# The usage of the word overlap

Tags: word-usage

> Sociologist C. Wright Mills used the term power elite to refer to his
>   theory that the United States is actually run by a small group
>   representing the most wealthy, powerful, and influential people in
>   business, government, and the military. According to Mills, their
>   decisions dictate the policies of this country more than those of the
>   voting public. **Mills also pointed out that the influence of the
>   power elite overlaps into many different areas.** For example, a
>   wealthy businessman may make large contributions to a particular
>   political candidate.

[Source](http://www.sparknotes.com/sociology/social-groups-and-organizations/section4.rhtml)

When I read the passage and the sentence, which was highlighted, I get what it means but when I look up the word overlap, the words I expected do not turn up as a synonym.For example what I got from the sentence is that the influence of the power elite overpower or exert more influence than the rest of the people in a society so power elite can change the direction in a way they want in different areas.But in Cambridge Dictionaries Online , there are two meaning is referenced to this word that are  :

[image]

But I don't think the word overlap implies exactly what I got from the word or the sentence.Because there is no the same level of power or influence in a society.Am I right?

Comment: Consider that areas of influence are represented by a Venn diagram. The area representing the influence of the power elite overlaps (or intersects) with other areas of influence

Comment: @Jim +1 I was going to say the exact same thing but you beat me to it.

Comment: @Jim if A ={1,2,3} B = { 1,2 } Can we say cluster A overlaps cluster B? Normally when two cluster has a intersection they are overlapped but in my example cluster A > or =  B.  Another example can we say The UK overlaps   England ( in terms of border )

Comment: In your example the **overlap** is {1,2}. If we had A = {1,2,3,4,5} and B = {1,3,5,7,11} the **overlap** would be {1,3,5}

Answer (score 4):

"Overlaps" refers to the fact that someone who is powerful in one area is often powerful in another area. For instance, Ronald Reagan was a well-paid "movie star" (in Hollywood), whose power "overlapped" into the political arena.